# Couchbase GO SDK case insensitive

Tags: go, couchbase

I'm running this code which is **case sensitive**:

```
cbft.NewMatchQuery("London").Field("Town")
```

How can I make the search **case insensitive**, so that searching for "London" or "london" would match "London" in the Couchbase database?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-full-text-cbft-for-content-management/) blog post:

> Full-Text Searches are case insensitive and use the match query
>   expression. In order to perform FTS, you must create Full-Text Index
>   on appropriate properties. You can create an index on one or more
>   properties.

You are using the cbft package (Couchbase Full Text), and probably you haven't set the Full-Text index on the appropriate properties (Town).
For setting up the index, read carefully [the documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/fts/fts-creating-indexes.html).